# Use Dask to return several dataframes after computing over a single Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

Is there any way for me to take a DataFrame (originally in Pandas, sample it with different random seeds and use Dask to return several Dataframes (one per random seed).

My very primitive understanding of Dask is that I can take a Dataframe, split it and then make computations over it but I was wondering if I could use Dask to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use [Dask Delayed](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html) to run arbitrary functions in parallel.

```
def sample(df: pandas.DataFrame, seed:int) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    ...

import dask

df = pandas.DataFrame(...)

dfs = [dask.delayed(sample)(df, seed) for seed in seeds]
dfs = dask.compute(*dfs)
```